# Best practice for multi-volume book

Tags: pdftex, compiling, books, multiple-files

One has to solve many problems when writing a large tex file, even worse when the output needed is more than one PDF (many volumes).

- The large tex file becomes very slow and the editor becomes irresponsive quickly. Also every compilation takes forever.
- One have to split the toc, the bibliography, the appendices, the index and maybe the preface between many volumes.
- If one decides to create a tex file for each volume, how can a theorem or eq be referenced, how can one have a continuous chapter, figure, theorem and page numbers?

Some links to help with these issues will help.

Comment: (1) editor becomes irresponsive quickly ... One with a lot of plugins?  LaTeX files are only plain text, many editors can edit quickly very longs texts but it they must check synntax , and spelling, and autocompletion, and  ... and ... with more and more plugins, at the end you will have some crawling more than a word porcessor   with a lot of figures.

Comment: (2) compilation takes forever .... KISS principle (keep it simple, sir)  how many kilometers have your preamble?

Comment: (3) there are some packages to work with sub-documents with different approaches:  search about `childdoc`, `combine`, `docmute`, `minidocument`, `subdocs`, subfile and `standalone`.

Comment: What are your design aims? A ToC per volume or an overall ToC? Similarly for Bibliography. Why split appendices between volumes -- each should be individual. Do you really expect your reader of volume 3 to be able to refer to an equation in volume 1? Basically I think that each volume should be as independent as possible.

Comment: @PeterWilson A detailed ToC per volume + a Toc of chapter names of other volumes. I want the page number, theorem number, figure number, etc. of vol2 not to start at 1. I can reference in vol3 a theorem number 145 of vol1.

Comment: @Fran I will check them, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking the best option here would be to do something along the lines of

```
\documentclass{...}
...
\includeonly{volume1}
...
\begin{document}
\include{volume1}
\include{volume2}
\include{volume3}
\end{document}
```

Your document class should handle things like resetting the page number to 1 at th beginning of each volume (assuming that's the desired choice) potentially restricting the table of contents, index etc. to the current volume.

Comment: The document class isn't book?

Comment: book would be a good starting point, but there are a number of customizations necessary that you might end up using a custom document class (that's what I mean about the your document class should handle... comment below).

Comment: @user5402 As you haven't bothered to provide an MWE how are we to know which class you have used. If you want help then please try and help us.